# Action Method Not Found -- Even Though It IS In The Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html-helper

My assumption after reading through the documentation was that we could use @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") to call an action method in a controller from a view.

Is that a false assumption? Because if my logic/assumption is wrong to begin with it would be helpful to know.

I have the following code in my HomeController.cs

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork()
{
        var dash = "dash equals nash";

        var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test2 username2", Email = "testemail2@gmail.com" };
        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "passwordGoesHere1!");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account");

            return View();
        }

        //AddErrors(result);
        return View();    
}
```

And I have the following script in my _Layout.cshtml

```
    @*script for someone who presses the send/email button*@ 
    <script>
        $("#sendButton").click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            @Html.Action("DidItWork", "Home")
        });
    </script>
```

Upon starting up the program, and during debugging, DidItWork() appears to be called without ever clicking the #sendButton -- why is that?

When stepping through, everything appears to work as long the user name and email are unique. However, at the end, once it is done, it goes to the `@Html.Action("DidItWork", "Home")` line and throws an exception.

Thoughts/suggestions for fixing this? The exception info is below:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
>   Inner Exception: {"The view 'DidItWork' or its master was not found or
>   no view engine supports the searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched:..."}

Comment: It's saying the **view** was not, found, not the *action*.  Are you sure you have a `DidItWork` view in the appropriate location?

Comment: You are using wrong helper use ``Url.Action()``

Comment: Thank you @KirkWoll I did not have DidItWork in the appropriate location because I didn't have a DidItWork view -- I thought Html.Action did something different. I'm going to try using Url.Action() instead as Ehsan mentioned. Thanks as well Ehsan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My assumption after reading through the documentation was that we
>   could use @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") to call an
>   action method in a controller from a view.
>
> Is that a false assumption?

No.

> Upon starting up the program, and during debugging, DidItWork()
>   appears to be called without ever clicking the #sendButton -- why is
>   that?

Because that's how the `Html.Action` helper works. It invokes the action **on the server** and inserts the result of this action in the view.

> Thoughts/suggestions for fixing this? The exception info is below:

Since you are talking about invoking an action using javascript, you should not be using server side view rendering such as `Html.Action` but rather client side scripting. For example you could use AJAX:

```
<script>
    $("#sendButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DitItWork", "Home")',
            success: function(reuslt) {
                // result will contain the execution of the DidItWork action.
                // Right now it is an error, because you don't seem to have defined
                // a DidItWork.cshtml page. Once you fix this it will work
                // as expected
                // Here you probably want to insert the result somewhere
                // in your markup
            }
        });
        // return false to cancel the default action and leave the AJAX call
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need the ajax or can I make the call to Url.Action by just swapping out the Http and Url part in my original code? I only ask because @EhsanSaijad mentioned that I was using the wrong helper above but there was no mention of ajax. Also thanks for the explanation Darin. I still don't have a great grasp on server/client side so this is something I can look into more.

Comment: `Url.Action` returns a string pointing to the url. It doesn't execute the action. The `Html.Action` helper executes the action on the server. If you want to execute some controller action when a button is clicked from the client you could either use AJAX or redirect the browser to the target url.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. As for your original answer when I use that method and debug the DidItWork method never appears to be called. However, it does appear to be going through all the steps required to create a new UserManager (e.g., ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>). For my clarification, is that what you were referring to when you said "Result will contain the execution of the DidItWork action"?

Answer (score 1):

This code segment

```
@Html.Action("DidItWork", "Home")
```

calling DidItWork action and your code returning View().During build actually you work to open Home/DidItWork.cshtml
so you must change your return statement to existing view.

Comment: Thanks Acebisli -- I assumed returning to existing view was just return View(); but it sounds like that's not the case. How do you return to existing view? Is that something that I need to know ahead of time that I manually put in (e.g., return View("Index"))

Comment: Yeah you can do it as View("~/Views/Product/Detail.cshtml", model);